# Selenium Web Driver: NoSuchElementError

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web, web-scraping

Salutations!

I'm building a web scraper using Selenium Web Driver and Excel VBA. For a specific website, I'm unable to find elements on the webpage, though I'm able to login to the website using the web driver.

Here's the website in question:

```
 WebsiteURL = "https://apps.availity.com/availity/web/public.elegant.login.HOME"
```

Here's the code in question:

```
 driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='payerDropDown_chzn']").Click
```

I've tried using byname, byname & byclass but none of the methods are able to find the element. I also tested this on multiple elements on the page and it won't work.

If you have any advice on how to find the elements, please let me know.

Comment: Can you post what the HTML surrounding that ID you're trying to find is?

Comment: Can you share the demo credentials?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I figured it out. I had to switch iframes in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't access the exact page because I don't have a login, but in the past when I've had issues finding elements it's because they were in an iframe. You have to activate/select (don't remember the term Selenium uses) an iframe to access elements within it. Or at least that's what I did.

Comment: agree with  SuperStew point, there should be frame in your page. check that, if so you need to switch to that frame before you operate element comes from that frame (you can think frame is another brower window, so you need to switch to it.)

Comment: That was exactly it! I appreciate the help.